# Unable to use HttpClient and HttpGet in Android

Tags: android

I would like to find out the weather information with using yahoo api. However, I get error when the following statement was executed. May I have some hints to solve it? Thanks.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();  // <--- error here
```

i had added the internet permission to mainfest.

```
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exercise.AndroidYahooWeatherDOM/com.exercise.AndroidYahooWeatherDOM.AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 22:06:27.310: E/AndroidRuntime(27723):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Comment: do a little research before asking.

Comment: may i have some hints/ keyword to do research. I really have no idea about the bug.

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` - right in the stack trace.

Comment: SO should auto downvote when detect `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in the question

Comment: lol 7min before this question there was similar question here too ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159633/getting-data-via-httpget-on-the-emulator this just need one more vote to close it ...

Comment: start by reading the stacktrace ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a separate thread or better an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), to do an Http connection

For example:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```